# How to retain value of state on page refresh

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am using localstorage.setItem() for storing state which will work on page refresh but localstorage is not working in my case. My state is not persistent on page refresh.
 I need to save user id globally which also need to be retained on page refresh throughout the project. Please help me out to resolve this issue.
        Any help would be appreciated.

```
        function setUserId(user_id = '', action) {
          switch (action.type) {
            case 'ADD_ID':
            return user_id = action.id;
            default:
            return user_id = action.id;
          }
        }
        const loadState = () => {
          try {
            const serializedState = localStorage.getItem("state");

            if (serializedState === null) {
              return undefined;
            }

            return JSON.parse(serializedState);

          } catch (err) {
            return undefined;
          }
        };

        const store = createStore(setUserId,loadState());

        function saveState(state) {
                try {
                    let serializedState = JSON.stringify(state);
                    localStorage.setItem("state",serializedState);
                }
                catch (err) {
                }
            }

        handleClick(event) {
      let that = this;
      axios.post(apiBaseUrl, payload)
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        if(response.status == 200){
          console.log("Login successfull");
          store.dispatch({
            type: 'ADD_ID',
            id: response.data.id
          })
          store.subscribe(() => {
            //this is just a function that saves state to localStorage
            saveState(store.getState());
          });

          that.setState({
            isLoggedIn: true,
            access_token: response.data.access_token,
            user_id: response.data.id
          })

        }

        else if(response.status == 204){
          console.log("Username password do not match");
          alert("username password do not match")
        }
        else{
          console.log("Username does not exists");
          alert("Username does not exist");
        }
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you use redux for persisting your data?

Comment: I am already using redux for storing state gloablly

Answer (score 0):

Remove `try/catch` from your `saveState()`. If you want to catch JavaScript errors anywhere in their child component tree. and try to console in `state` in `saveState()`.

Comment: console.log(state) in `saveState`

Comment: Please share your complete component.

Comment: this is almost completed except its UI rendering part

Comment: please convert this to react component